# Hibernate many-to-many mapping referencing partial composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

My problem is like this one: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002125

I have the following tables in my schema:

- a table A with a composite key (attr1, attr2);
- a table B with a pk (attr3);
- and a table A_B which is a relationship table between A and B with a composite key (fk_attr1, fk_attr3), where fk_attr1 and fk_attr3 references the fields attr1 and attr2, respectively

The attr2 is not used in the relationship.

I generated the mapping java classes with hibernate plugin, and the generated code looks like this:

**class A**

```
private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>(0);
private AId id;

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "attr1", column = @Column(name = "attr1", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "attr2", column = @Column(name = "attr2", nullable = false)) })
public AId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "A_B", catalog = "my_schema", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_attr1", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_attr3", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<B> getBs() {
    return this.bs;
}
```

**class B**

```
private Set<A> as = new HashSet<A>(0);

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "A_B", catalog = "my_schema", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_attr3", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_attr1", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<A> getAs() {
    return this.as;
}
```

**class AId** (the id for entity A)

```
private String attr1;
private Long attr2;

@Column(name = "attr1", nullable = false)
public String getAttr1() {
    return this.attr1;
}

@Column(name = "attr2", nullable = false)
public Long getAttr2() {
    return this.attr2;
}
```

But it always generates this exception:

**org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering A from B has the wrong number of column. should be 2**

What is the right way to accomplish this relationship with Hibernate?

Comment: Why are you not including attr2 in the join table A_B ?

Comment: Because it is a legacy database which I can't change. We would rather stop using Hibernate than changing our schema, but I want to make it to work with Hibernate